# Why does my h2o auto-encoder have so many input nodes?

Tags: r, h2o, autoencoder

I am trying to train an auto-encoder model in R with h2o to detect anomalies in my dataset:
[image: my dataset]

Here is my code:

```
df <- read.csv(file=inputFile) # extract dataframe

feature_names <- names(df)

train_df <- df # Use whole dataset for training for this example

# -- Now train auto-encoder model --
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init()
h2o.removeAll() # Close clusters that were already running

train_h2o <- as.h2o(train_df) # Put data in h2o dataframe

# Create deep learning model
result_model = h2o.deeplearning(x = feature_names, training_frame = train_h2o,
                               autoencoder = TRUE,
                               hidden = c(6,5,6),
                               epochs = 50)
```

Then after the model trains successfully, I enter `result_model` and get:

```
  layer units      type dropout       l1       l2 mean_rate rate_rms momentum
1     1   798     Input  0.00 %       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA
2     2     6 Rectifier  0.00 % 0.000000 0.000000  0.018308 0.110107 0.000000
3     3     5 Rectifier  0.00 % 0.000000 0.000000  0.002325 0.001377 0.000000
4     4     6 Rectifier  0.00 % 0.000000 0.000000  0.001975 0.001191 0.000000
5     5   798 Rectifier      NA 0.000000 0.000000  0.010888 0.064831 0.000000
```

The layer units are:
798, 6, 5, 6, 798, even though it was supposed to have 7 input nodes.

Can anyone help with this? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: The input variables look categorical, these need to be transformed into a binary matrix. You could see how many columns you get using `model.matrix`

Comment: How do I turn them into a binary matrix?

Comment: Well i'd guess that h20 is doing this behind the scenes (caveat Ive never used it) but that would explain why you are getting so many columns/inputs. Try running `ncol(model.matrix(~.-1, df))` to get a rough number of columns (it will miss afew)

Comment: Error message: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: But if you're asking how many columns my dataframe has, it is about 730

Comment: well from your screenshot the only column which could have one level is `Plant` -- id check that

Comment: What do you mean it could have one level?

Comment: re "it is about 730" ... now im confused; you mention "..supposed to have 7 input nodes" and  (the screenshot of) your dataframe has 7 columns. Im taking a punt that your input has 798 due to expansion of your seven columns into a binary matrix.

Comment: re "What do you mean it could have one level?" ...  that was in reponse to your error message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061965/why-does-my-h2o-auto-encoder-have-so-many-input-nodes#comment111516783_63061965

Comment: re "Im taking a punt that your input has 798 due to expansion of your seven columns into a binary matrix." I thought that the seven columns mean the neural network would have seven input nodes, since those are the seven variables. If I wanted the algorithm to encode the strings somehow, instead of treating them as categorical data, how would I do that?

Comment: If it had seven numeric variables then yes you would have seven inputs. The categorical need to be transformed into a numeric (similarly for linear regression etc)  -- this is done by dummy coding / binary matrix ...

Comment: Ok, I will try something along those lines. Thank you!

Comment: Im not sure that you need to *try something* as given the input dimension reported by h20 it is likely doing this already. But for your own peace of mind / understanding it is worth creating the binary matrix manually and checking its dimension

Comment: But my aim is to have the strings encoded, not used as categories as I could get new strings in my test data. I am looking into using ```categorical_encoding=labelEncoder```, do you think this would work?

Comment: with label encoding you are assuming some ordering between the levels of each category and then model may learn this. This is often not sensible.

Comment: So what should I opt for instead?

Comment: what is the issue with binary matrix (aka dummy variables/ one-hot encoding)? If it is that you may get levels in the test set that were not in the training then you can account for this when you create the datasets.

Comment: The problem is that when the model will be used, it might encounter strings it has never seen before, so would binary encoding work with it?

Comment: perhaps you could have a look at categorical embeddings but we are now getting away from your original question. If you need more theoretical advice try https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first layer in an DNN is the input layer -- that is the number of variables (or encoded variables) you have in your training set.

To summarize the comments above, your training frame is being expanded (by default, one-hot encoded) for any categorical columns that you have.  Given the screenshot of your dataset, you seem to have mostly all categorical columns (and they must have a total number of categories of ~798).  So what you're seeing is reasonable.  Since it's an autoencoder, the output layer is the same size as the input layer, which is why the last layer is 798 units as well.